# cudaMemset doesn't seem to set the required value

Tags: cuda

I have the following simple program to test `cudaMemset`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
using namespace std;
__global__ void kernel(int *input){
    input[threadIdx.x] += threadIdx.x;
}
int main() {
    size_t size = 5; 
    int *h_ptr, *d_ptr;
    h_ptr = new int[size];

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_ptr, sizeof(int) * size);
    cudaMemset(d_ptr, 10, sizeof(int) * size);

    kernel<<<1, size>>>(d_ptr);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(h_ptr, d_ptr, sizeof(int)*size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cout<<h_ptr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

I expected the result would be `[10 11 12 13 14]` instead I'm getting garbage values.

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[cudaMemset](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee.html) works just like standard [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) function except that it is for device memory.
It sets the value of every **byte** of the specified memory location. You are trying to set the value of integer as a whole which is not possible with memset.

In the provided example, cudaMemset is setting the value of every byte to 10.
It means the memory will be initialized like this

`0A0A0A0A0A0A0A......` (in hex notation).

So when you read it as a 32-bit integer, you will get:

`168430090` in decimal

The values are not garbage, these are the expected results.

`[168430090 168430091 168430092 168430093 168430094]`

Comment: write a kernel that inizializes your array :)

Comment: Yes, an initialization kernel is required in this case.

Comment: See also [memset integer array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202411/memset-integer-array) and [cudaMemset() usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387101/cudamemset-usage).